# MikTex Net Installer Installation Failure

Tags: miktex, installing

I get the following error, no matter which internet connection I use:

> "The operation could not be completed for the following reason:
> A connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established.
> For help, visit [www.miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect"](http://www.miktex.org/kb/fix-couldnt-connect%22)

I am facing similar problems when I try to install packages in the Basic Miktex version using Miktex console.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Officially this question might be considered off topic. But a few suggestions might help solving the issue. First question however will be: Are you using a Windows version prior to Windows 10? MikTeX won't install anymore on Windows 7 (and 8) as of January 22, 2023.

Comment: @alchemist I am currently using Windows 11, but I had the same problem on Windows 10.

Comment: Just adking the next obvious question: could a firewall blocking the MikTeX installer / updater? You obviously have internet connection, so it could be that something is blocking specific connections. Things like this are always difficult to trace, so just take it one obvious step at a time and see where something seems off.