# Can't update my MikTex. Getting an error

Tags: update

When I try to update my MikTex, I get the error "Something went wrong while checking for updates. A connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established."
I'm running MikTex on a Windows PC, in Windows 10.
Might anyone be able to help me figure out why I can't update. It does say it's been a long time since I updated.
Thank you!!
Patrick

Comment: looks as if you are not alone https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675879/miktex-net-installer-installation-failure

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to download the latest basic MikTeX version and install that one. To save your older installed version just rename the folder. There are also entries in `AppData\Local` and `AppData\Roaming` that you can rename.

Comment: Sometimes specific mirror sites go down.  If you wait a day, it might work.